# ReactJ How to render current listitem's nested array into an select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I working on an React App where I receive an array which contains certain days and timeslots, e.g. each of these days have specific timeslots. Right now, I render the array in an list and toggle an "active" class. Additionally I want to render the specific timeslots as options inside a `<select>` but I dont know how to achieve it? Also, I want to only display for example five days, with the possible to "load" more days and finally how to for example change the state when a day + a timeslot is selected?

I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/puhcn9v6/4/) here with my current code

This is what I got so far:

```
export default class BookingPage extends React.Component{
constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
        step: 1,
        availableDates: [
           {
               "day": "22-01-2018",
               "slots" : [
                   "13.00 - 14.00",
                   "14.00 - 15.00",
                   "15.00 - 16.00",
                   "16.00 - 17.00",
                   "17.00 - 18.00"
               ]
           },
           {
                "day": "23-01-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "24-01-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "25-01-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "26-01-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "27-01-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "28-01-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "29-01-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "30-01-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "31-01-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "01-02-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },
            {
                "day": "02-02-2018",
                "slots" : [
                    "13.00 - 14.00",
                    "14.00 - 15.00",
                    "15.00 - 16.00",
                    "16.00 - 17.00",
                    "17.00 - 18.00"
                ]
            },                                                                                                                                                                             
        ]
    }
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="section-booking">
            <div className="section-content-wrapper">
                <div className="section-content">
                    <div className="step-indicator">

                    </div>
                    <div className="booking-picker">
                        <BookingSlider dates={this.state.availableDates} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class BookingSlider extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
          activeItem: null
       }
}

onItemActive(item) {
    this.setState({activeItem: item})
}
render() {
    let items = this.props.dates.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <BookingSlots 
            key={index} 
            item={item} 
            onItemActive={this.onItemActive.bind(this)} 
            active={item === this.state.activeItem}
        >
        </BookingSlots>
        );
    });     
    return(
        <div className="booking-date-wrapper">
            <ul>
                {items}
            </ul>
            <div>
                <select>
                    <option value="">OPTIONS HERE</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

  }
}

class BookingSlots extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
      super()
   }
   setActive() {
      this.props.onItemActive(this.props.item);      
   }

   render() {
      let item = this.props.item;
      return (
        <li className={this.props.active ? 'active' : null} onClick={this.setActive.bind(this)}>
         {item.day}   
       </li>
    );
  }    
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome :-)

Comment: based on what you need to render select options, can your slots be different

Comment: Yes, the slots can be totally different - this is just an example

Comment: Then how and which slots do you want to render as select options

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri have you checked out the fiddle? When i for example click on 24-01-2018, the list-item gets an active class, so I want to render the slots from that date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just render the options from the `activeItem` state like

```
  <select>
       {this.state.activeItem && this.state.activeItem.timeSlots.map((slot, index)=> {
           return <option key={index} value={slot}>{slot}</option>
       })}
  </select>
```

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/puhcn9v6/4/)**